# Is worth avoiding newing up services in autofac container?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to use autofac in a console application that uses some services inside a class library project.

My container config is something like this

```
public static IContainer Configure()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<DateService>().As<IDateService>();

    builder.Register(paramService => new ParamService(paramService.Resolve<IDateService>()).As<IParamService>();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

But in the console app I'm not actually using the DateService for anything (i.e. it's only usage is for being the parameter of the newed ParamService in the container) so I wonder if it's worth doing that or would be just enough to do

```
public static IContainer Configure()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.Register(paramService => new ParamService(new DateService()).As<IParamService>();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Is there any downside for that I can't think of?

It wouldn't be a big deal but in the real scenario I would need to register different things for the same interface and other relatively more complex scenarios so I think if there's nothing wrong with newing up the parameters I would go for it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One downside of directly instantiating a service would be that **other registrations wouldn't be able to override the implementation of `IDateService`** - they'd have to change an unrelated registration. If your app gets big enough and you start splitting registrations into modules, that restriction may be unclear and folks may wonder why the `IDateService` everywhere else is the one they registered but it's not properly getting injected in this one instance.

Another downside would be **if `DateService` is `IDisposable`** - Autofac will track disposables and clean them up for you. In this case, you'd need to dispose of the `DateService` yourself.

The benefit of doing the direct instantiation is that **it's technically faster** - you're not going through the layers of Autofac to end up with `new DateService()`.

**There is no recommendation one way or the other** - you'll need to choose based on your application's needs.

Answer (score 1):

To build upon Travis's answer, registering `DateService` separately also allows you to simplify your registration of `ParamService` to:

```
builder.RegisterType<ParamService>().As<IParamService>();
```

I prefer this syntax over the original because in the event that `ParamService` is modified to require an addition constructor parameter, its Autofac registration remains unchanged.